# Why is the __restrict__ modifier not enforced?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, restrict-qualifier

If a function parameter is annotated `const int &x` and I try to do `x++` in the function body, I get a compile time error for modifying a read-only reference. But if I use the `__restrict__` modifier like so:

```
void foo(int & __restrict__ a, int & __restrict__ b) {
    if (a == 1)
        b = 2;
    if (a == 2)
        b = 3;
}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    foo(x, x); // should be illegal?
    cout << x;
}
```

...I do not get a compile time error. If I run this code unoptimized the output is `3`, but if I run it with `-O1` or higher the output is `2`. It seems like detecting `x` to be passed twice would be straightforward and easy to disallow. Why does C++ protect against bad use of `const` but not bad use of `__restrict__`?

Comment: it is undefined behavior. I am just not sure enough to post an answer, because I have difficulties to find proper reference for C++

Comment: Note that C++ isn't doing _anything_ with `__restrict__`, because it is an implementation extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are looking at `__restrict__` backwards.**

`__restrict__` is an implementation extension that the programmer can use to signal *intent*, to maximise generated code quality and performance ("optimisations").

It is not a check, or an added constraint on the program.

It is not part of the type system, so it's not part of the function's type, so it cannot be enforced at callsites (in general).

It is like some other extensions (such as `__builtin_unreachable`), that *you* use to tell the compiler something.

In this case, you're telling it "I am not referring to the pointee via any other pointer".

You're not asking it "please stop me from referring to the pointee via any other pointer".

C and C++ compilers already perform strong "aliasing" checks where they can. The `__restrict__` keyword is a way for *you* to tell *it* "I am sure about this", in cases where the automatic aliasing detection cannot work (due to, for example, translation unit boundaries). Because the automatic aliasing detection cannot work, `__restrict__` cannot be enforced.

And, even if it could be, that would be the opposite of the purpose of the modifier.

Answer (score 3):

In the very general case it is impossible to diagnose it at compile-time. Just as one trivial counter example, consider:

```
 void foo(int* __restrict__ a, int * __restrict__ b);

 int x;
 int y;
 std::cin >> x >> y;
 int* a = (x%2) ? &x : &y;
 int* b = (y%2) ? &x : &y;
 foo(a,b);
```

No way the compiler can know if `a` and `b` will point to the same `int`. Actually if the compiler could do such analysis, there would be no need for the `__restrict__` qualifier, because then the compiler could by itself figure out if two pointers are used to access same memory.

Answer (score 2):

It is not that easy to detect `restrict` violation in general. Suppose you have a function

```
void bar(int* p1, int* p2) {
    foo(*p1, *p2);
}
```

What should a compiler do in this case?

In some cases (like in your example), `restrict` violation can be detected and is detected by some compilers. For example, GCC with `-Wrestrict` produces a warning:

> warning: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 2

GCC [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) on `-Wrestrict` reads:

> Warn when an object referenced by a `restrict`-qualified parameter (or, in C++, a `__restrict`-qualified parameter) is aliased by another argument, or when copies between such objects overlap.

You can turn this warning into an error using with `-Werror=restrict` option.